# Openai ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error: "Invalid URL (POST /chat/v1/completions)"/ Raw response for the API , Status code 400

Tags: json, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I was planning on developing a chatgpt app and I keep on facing the same error.

> There was an issue setting up your call.
> Raw response for the API
> Status code 400
> "error": {
> "message": "You must provide a model parameter",
> "type": "invalid_request_error",
> "param": null,
> "code": null

This is the code I used:

```
conversation='{
  "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  "messages": [
    {
      "role": "system",
      "content": "You are a helpful assistant."
    },
    {
      "role": "user",
      "content": "Hello!"
    }
  ]
}'

curl -X POST https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY" \
  -d "$conversation"
```

I tried it without using variables and all. Gave the API code but still faced the same issue.
I am new to using API and all. So please help me out here.